# How to display the list of objects dynamically in the matrix format jsp page?

Tags: list, jsp, grid, format

I want to display list of objects and display like matrix grid table 
For example :

Cloth type    xs      large  xl  xxl

Blouse       10       15       20     1

Shirt         1        2       8     10

Cloth type, size type like xs, l, xl,etc and values are stored in the same object , for example :
obj.product ="Blouse"
obj.sizetype=xs
obj.value=10 , I am not sure how to display all the data from the list of objects. Please let me know if you have any experience developing this kind of pages.

Thanks in advance !!!!

Comment: I'd say any computer science / software engineering student should be able to solve this kind of tasks. You have to process your data twice, once to find out, what product names (types, i.e. "Blouse", "Shirt", ..) and sizes are there, the second time to display them. Hint: one `Map<String, Integer>` for each line (key=size), one `Map<String, Map<String, Integer>>` to keep all the lines (key=product name), and a `Set<String>` to keep track of the all available sizes.

Comment: I did the same thing as you mentioned before even i write this post . the reason i posted the question is I have to develop this page through list of object. For example : Object.clothtype=Blouse Object.size =xs Object.value=10 . I am not sure how to display this three values from the same object will be displayed as grid.

Comment: Using only list, without processing it into a data structure, that fits the required display format, is - IMHO - impossible.

Theoretically, you could put your objects into a JSP page (the generated HTML code, actually) as a list of JSON objects, but to display them in a grid (i.e. in a table), you need then to process them with Javascript the same way I suggested above.

Comment: Will give a try above. :) Thanks though :)